# Fluent Validation - custom localization

Tags: c#, localization, fluentvalidation, fluentvalidation-2.0

Using FluentValidation I want to implement my own localization, as I translate my messages using a 3rd party service/source.

How do I replace LocalizedStringSource with my own implementation? Is it possible?

This is an idee ( [Griffin localization and Fluent Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474293/griffin-localization-and-fluent-validation) ) but still doesn't tell me how to use it.

Best regards,
Cezar.